# When hiding/showing navigation bar, the nav bar is visible when the page is refreshed then disappears when I scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a page where the second nav bar appears when scrolling, and should be hidden when the window is at top: 0. When refreshing the page, the nav bar is visible, and then disappears when scrolling to then appear at the scrollPos set to appear.

How do I make it so that it is hidden when the page is refreshed?

The webpage is www.fareastfestival.com please take a look to help.

Here is the JS code I have used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var navOffset = $("nav1").offset().top;

    $("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
    $(".nav-placeholder").height($("nav").outerHeight());

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(); 

        if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
            $("nav").removeClass("hide");
            $("nav").addClass("fixed");
            $(".navlogo").show();
        } 
        else {
            $("nav").addClass("hide");
            $("nav").removeClass("fixed");
            $(".navlogo").hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the hide class to nav in your html file like so `<nav class="hide">`

Comment: In your html file, give the object that has the .nav class the .hide class as well

Comment: Can you add that part of your html file with nav to your question?

Comment: change <nav> to <nav class="hide">

Comment: Ahhh Legend - thank you very much, this has worked..... Sorry, my first time coding! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just add the .hide class to your HTML element. 
Here's an example (line 7):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var navOffset = $("nav1").offset().top;

    $("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
    $(".nav-placeholder").height($("nav").outerHeight());
    $("nav").addClass("hide");

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(); 

        if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
            $("nav").removeClass("hide");
            $("nav").addClass("fixed");
            $(".navlogo").show();
        } 
        else {
            $("nav").addClass("hide");
            $("nav").removeClass("fixed");
            $(".navlogo").hide();
        }
    });

});
```

The above code adds the class dynamically. You could also just added to the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for helping, the post above has solved the problem. Thanks again